# Upload many photos from iPhone to Flickr

Tags: flickr, iphone

What's the easiest way to upload many photos from an iPhone to Flickr.

Email only allows 5 a time. Official app just 1!

I'd like to avoid transfering to desktop first if possible.

Comment: Seems like the best answers you'll get will be native apps.  You should try asking this on gadgets.stackexchange.com

Comment: I did toy with that, but it's a web app (Flickr) specific problem .....?

Comment: Have you tried tapping `Add Item` ??? I got to 6 in the App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Version 1.1 and later (Release Date: 2009-12-03), You can now upload multiple photos and videos at a time. All of this is possible by just tapping `Add Item`.

I will add some screenshots later.

Comment: Simple, but not very obvious - thanks!